# How do I manage data for a Point Of Sales Android app written in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, sql, react-native, redux

I am making a react-native POS application on Android. I am storing data(items, employees, etc.) in an online MySQL database. I also need to sync orders across all POS's of a restaurant.

The implementation I have right now is fetching all the data needed when the app opens and storing it in redux, then accessing the data from redux, essentially using redux as a local database. Is this the best way to do things? Will there be performance issues if the dataset is large? Should I use a local sqlite database?

Comment: As one user mentioned, this approach has concurrency problems. Also it should be noted that AsyncStorage already uses SQLite if it is available, and if not it uses RocksDB and native code on iOS to handle large and small values so the size of your store should not be an issue

Comment: Why dont you try android - java/kotlin for android pos application ? 
i think Java/Kotlin are stronger languages

Answer (score 0):

This in my opinion is not the right way of doing it.
1) If the dataset is large is going to take a long time to download all the state to redux and also is going to make the application allocate a huge amount of memory to store all the data.
2) I you have multiple users modifying the database locally how do you synch all the changes.What do you do with concurrency, two user modifying the same record, etc.

I think what you need to do is to implement a backend service that centralise all the changes, that page and allow search in the dataset.That way your ui only download the data it needs and all crud operations are in synch and manage by the server.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on memory. The problem with not storing data locally is that we want the user flow to be instant and fluid as cashiers and waiters will need to move fast. This is why I want all the data to be loaded locally somewhere so there is no loading/waiting time between any actions a user might make. I do have a centralized MySQL database that stores the data online that will handle all the posts/puts/etc. I am planning on setting up a network socket to sync orders.